# Function gives NAN instead of a string

Tags: javascript, function, output

i'm a beginner in JS and i have a problem with this function:
first of all i defined it :

```
function highAndLow(numbers){
     numbers = numbers.replace(/ /g,",");
     let high = Math.max(numbers);
     let min = Math.min(numbers);
     console.log("The max value is "+high+ ", and the minimum is "+min);
};
```

and when i call it :

```
console.log(highAndLow("1 2 3 4 5"));
```

i get the following output :

```
The max value is NaN, and the minimum is NaN
```

So please could you show where is the problem and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function highAndLow(numbers) {
     numbers = numbers.split(' ').map(n => +n);
     let high = Math.max(...numbers);
     let min = Math.min(...numbers);
     return "The max value is "+ high+ ", and the minimum is "+ min;
}

console.log(highAndLow("1 2 3 4 5"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making three mistakes.

- You are using `replace()` on string. Which will output a string. You can't pass string to `Math.min/max`. You should use `split()` by `' '`
- Even if you `split()` the elements of arrays will be strings. You can convert it to numbers using `map()`
- `Math.min/max` doesn't expects array as argument. If you want to pass array use Spread Operator

```js
function highAndLow(numbers){
     numbers = numbers.split(' ').map(Number)
     let high = Math.max(...numbers);
     let min = Math.min(...numbers);
     console.log("The max value is "+high+ ", and the minimum is "+min);
};

console.log(highAndLow("1 2 3 4 5"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
function highAndLow(numbers){
     numbers = numbers.split(" ");
     let high = Math.max(...numbers);
     let min = Math.min(...numbers);
     console.log("The max value is "+high+ ", and the minimum is "+min);
};


 highAndLow("1 2 3 4 5");
```

Comment: thank you very much, i have a question please : why did you add those 3 dots before the variable number in the third and forth row ?

Comment: @MohammedTouati That is called spread operator. `Math.max/min` expects individual arguments like `Math.max(1,2,3)`. So to convert `Math.max([1,2,3])` to `Math.max(1,2,3)` be use spread operator.

Comment: @MohammedTouati ,this is spread (ES5) ,  to change [1,2,3,4,5]}  to  1,2,3,4,5 .  because min and max functions accepts  only elements

Answer (score 1):

I think the main missunderstanding is that:

```
 Math.max("1,2,3")
```

and

```
  Math.max(1, 2, 3)
```

are equal (the first is what you do, the second is what you want). They are not as in the first case you pass a string to `Math.max`, while in the second you pass multiple numbers. To turn the string into an array of numbers, you can `.split` it into an array of strings first, then parse the strings into numbers. That array can then be spread as arguments:

```
  Math.max(..."1 2 3".split(" ").map(Number))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is Math.max expects a collection and you are passing a string which just contains the numbers. COnvert the collection into an array and pass it.

```js
function highAndLow(numbers){
     numbers = numbers.replace(/ /g,",");
     var numbersList = numbers.split(",").map(function(num){
      return parseInt(num);
     });
     let high = Math.max(...numbersList);
     let min = Math.min(...numbersList);
     console.log("The max value is "+high+ ", and the minimum is "+min);
};

console.log(highAndLow("1 2 3 4 5"));
```